# use mercurial with linux Mint

Tags: linux, mercurial, linux-mint

i'm currently trying Linux Mint with Mate and i'm looking for a solution to manage my mercurial repo.
Tortoise-hg doesn't seems to be compatible with caja.
Except command line, what are your solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

for information, tortoise-hg as caja extension build on nautilus
http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/plugins